# Modelling Relationships Between Inherited Types into ORM

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jdo, data-modeling

I am looking for advice or alternatives on how to model the following relationships.

**Consider:**

[image]

**And an application of said relations:**

[image]

Mr. Warlord has many choices, however if a resource disappears, his choice cascade-dly removes. Now Firearms and Bullets are both resources.  Firearms can use many kinds of bullets, (FMJ,HP,P+,Explosive?..). Bullets can also be used in a variety of firearms (AK,M60,M14).  So I would also like to ensure that if a Bullet is no longer available, the aforementioned Firearm relationship would no longer exists, and vice-versa.

Hopefully my fantasy example of perk earning Warlords paints a clear picture.

Resources are abstract. Though they exist in the datastore for constraint purposes, I would never instantiate a generic resource. And I could have many more types (henchmen, helicopters, werewolves,...) each with quite different attributes. They exist in the first case to avoid a polymorphic foreign key situation with the ChoicesEarned.

You will notice that Resource Type 2 does not contain a `Set<Type1>`, but merely the reference to the `(Long)ResourceId` of some Firearm. (Bullets cannot hold firearms, even if the reverse is true, and for sake of argument, yes these magical guns can shoot many types of bullets).

Why do I have collections of ID's, not objects? Well If I add a type of bullet, it seems more efficient to add an Id reference to an association table than to retrieve the firearm and "add" a bullet object to it. That way too, when I retrieve a firearm object, I don't also retrieve all of the bullets it could possibly use. (Less memory overhead for all those objects, instead just a bunch of Ids).

***So what was the question?:***

1.) This doesn't seem like an uncommon pattern. Is there a better way to model it?

2.) Am I being an OOP heretic to use references instead of objects? Should I just use Objects?

***My Main Problem***

3.) If 1 and 2 aren't the case, How can I model this in JDO? I have experimented for a couple days and the problem I keep having is that JDO can't seem to recognize the relationship between the Sets of Longs. Every example I have found shows the use of Composition objects, not M-N attribute references. If I don't specify another persisted object there seems to be some confusion. An attribute of a persisted object doesn't seem to work.

**UPDATE:**

I received an answer from the DataNucleus forum today, [Here is the thread](http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7067)
The problem was related to my Question #2 above. My attempt at saving some memory overhead was the source of my difficulties. <strike>I cannot establish a relationship between collections whose element types are not other persisted classes without jury-rigging. I will need to re-design a little bit.</strike>

**SOLUTION:**

See my Answer below

I appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say that resources only share a common interface but no commonality of existence?  Ie, there is never reason to have a list of Bullets and Perks together.

Comment: @MarkRobinson - I may not be following, but the list of Perks would really only serve to direct "access". I would not need the Bullets and Perks at the same time, rather I would select resources from the list of Perks, and later on retrieve those resources to be used together.   Does that address what you were getting at?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing what resources bring to the table in this design; it looks to me like you'll need a bunch of type casting to use resources like this. Can you expound on this a little? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielLyons - The fact is, I wouldn't need them save for the problem of datastore constraints. I can't have choices that are FK to _either_ Firearms or Bullet tables. To me it's a tradeoff to ensure that there is an appropriate linkage in the RDB. Otherwise, I would have to move those integrity checks into the application. (Which is do-able, but I don't know how appropriate)

Comment: @Sp3igel The FK would go the other way though, wouldn't it? From Firearm and Bullet to Warlord.

Comment: @DanielLyons - Do you mean to add multiple FK columns to the "ChoicesEarned" table? I don't follow the relationship directly to Warlord that your saying.

Comment: FKs in the database work in the opposite direction to pointers in programming languages: the destination points back to the source rather than the container holding onto the contained. So unless I'm missing something, I suspect you're putting the FK on the wrong end in the database.

Comment: @DanielLyons - No I understand the concept of FK's pointing back to their PK sources. I think I am on a separate page from you though, so I apologize. I don't understand your comment "From Firearm and Bullet to Warlord." Their only relationship comes through the ChoicesEarned join table. And I must generalize, since ChoicesEarneds resourceId column cannot point back to more than one table. If i've got it totally wrong, please point me to some reading material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not convinced that this model was [un-achievable](http://www.datanucleus.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,7067), so I continued to experiment with it. Despite the fact that the collections where not comprised of persisted classes, but instead just the IDs of those persisted instances, the final datastore model would be the same either way.

I wanted to have the collections of longs on each side of the relationship be stored together in a [join table](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/guides/jdo/many_many/index.html). I also wanted to ensure that these longs (representing the PKs of the **far** side of the relation) would be configured as a compound PK with each half pointing back to the table it represented. Despite this seeming a pretty trivial setup I had repeated issues with a third column being created in the join table by the JDO schema creator. Instead of matching the (Long)Id's to the related object, it was seeing them as "element" and dumping them into this third column. This of course broke the primary key, and resulted in exceptions being thrown when any of the objects were persisted.

None of the documentation offered any solution for this, so I am offering it below:

1. I stopped using [annotations](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jdo/metadata.html) or a [seperate ORM file](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jdo/orm/metadata_orm.html) and stuck with just a package.jdo metadata file. (this may not be necessary, but it's good practice(edit XMl vs. Class) and it made things simpler.)
2. I gave **specific names* to the join tables columns so that they would not auto generate their own.
3. I matched the join instructions on both sides of the relationship. This means specifying the table, the joined column name. This is not suggested in [the docs](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jdo/orm/many_to_many.html), but this way the Id's go into the right columns regardless of which collection they come from (where before without the specific instructions, they reversed the order and added more FK constraints... why I don't understand).

So the .jdo metadata looks as follows:

```
    <class name="Firearm" table="APP_JDO_FIREARMS">
        <inheritance strategy="new-table"/>
        <field name="name"/>

         ...
        <field name="bullets" mapped-by="firearms" table="APP_JDO_BULLET_FIREARM">
            <collection element-type="java.lang.Long"/>
            <join>
                <column name="FIREARM_ID"/>
            </join>
            <element>
                <column name="BULLET_ID"/>
            </element>
        </field>
    </class>

    <class name="Bullet" table="APP_JDO_BULLETS">
        <inheritance strategy="new-table"/>
        <field name="name"/>

        ...
        <field name="firearms" persistence-modifier="persistent" mapped-by="bullets" table="APP_JDO_BULLET_FIREARM">
            <collection element-type="java.lang.Long"/>
            <join>
                <column name="BULLET_ID"/>
            </join>
            <element>
                <column name="FIREARM_ID"/>
            </element>
        </field>
    </class>
```

The above metadata is different from normal in that it specifies the join relationship on **both** ends.  Normally you only need to specify it on one side. Doing it on both ends is being a little more forceful and not letting JDO try and figure out what to do.

I have confirmed that this way correctly sets up all of the PK, FK constraints as desired too. Even after dropping all the tables and letting JDO recreate them, it does it as desired.

This might have been trivial for some people, but this took me many hours to work out. Hopefully it will save somebody else the headache in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JDO so I am going to answer your question from the perspective of JPA and in a general way.

When it comes to mapping inheritance with an ORM you need to ask yourself the following questions.

1) Are you looking for ploymorphic query support. i.e. do you want to do a query for objects of type Resources and get back a list of objects of type Bullets and Fire arms.

If you don't need a polymorphic query you will want to use @MappedSuperclass which means that your base class contains annotations for mapping meta data which are inherited by the subclasses but the base class itself does not have an identity and therefore is not queryable but you can query for the sub classes.

If you do need polymorphic queries then you can have three possible table structures for mapping inheritance these are called strategies in JPA.

1. Table per concrete class
2. Single table with discriminator column
3. One table per class in the inheritance hierarchy (what you have in your question)

Each of those three inheritance mapping strategies have their pros and cons in terms of effort they put on the database. for example the single table with discriminator column would lead to a sparse table with lots of column but there are no joins required for a polymorphic query.

Many of the JPA books give a very good explanation of the tradeoffs between the three approaches, the important thing is to make sure you know what those trade offs are so you can pick the best approach for your app.

http://www.apress.com/9781430219569 has a decent discussion of the issues with mapping inheritance.

Comment: Hi ams - JDO in fact has virtually these same strategies, so your thoughts are very applicable. I added some additional info to the question.